# xCode complaining after converting project to ARC

Tags: ios, warnings, automatic-ref-counting

After converting project to ARC, The converting operation removed all the - `assign, retain` from the @properties decelerations, And left `nonatomic` only.

```
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cameraToggleButton;
```

Even thogh "HE DID IT", xCode gives warnings on all the declarations in the project:

[image: xcode warnings]

What is the problem?
And what should I do?

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion did not go well even though XCode did it, it just failed to do so. What you have to do is basically make the properties that were declared as assign, declared as weak, and the ones that were declared as retain, now declared as strong.

This is however not always the case, which is why you should take a look at this [Transitioning to ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) before proceeding.

Hope that helps.